# What is the dangerous region in The Void and how should I deal with it?

Tags: x4-foundations

I was exploring in The Void yesterday, using travel mode to transit through one of the asteroid belts. Suddenly, the computer voice tells me that there’s a dangerous area, hull critical and then **boom!**

So, what’s going on there? I see some yellowish asteroids but it’s not clear what ripped through my shields and peeled my hull so fast. Is there a special upgrade that I need if I ever want to mine those rocks?

Comment: I suppose these are meant to be radioactive asteroids and the safest way to deal with them is to charge through them at full travel mode speed which should only lead to minor shield damage.

Comment: @SEJPM, well that's an interesting idea. Could you mine away all the asteroids and achieve safety?

Comment: From what I've read on the forums, it appears that NPC ships are also affected by the damage. So the best one could hope for is a) the asteroids are actually the source and Egosoft didn't just mark the area of space as "contaminated" and put the asteroids there as a warning sign and b) out-of-sector ships are not affected and can in fact mine and destroy these asteroids. I don't have relieable information on either of these assumptions.

Comment: i believe asteroids respawn in x4

Answer (score 1):

As far as I perceived, only ships in the sensor range of your ship you're in take the damage.
So you mining should not be a problem as far as you don't visit the sites -.-

Comment: This isn’t true. If you bring up the map when you are in another sector, you can watch ships take damage as they transit this region.

Comment: Then it's just another bug I guess. Nothing I'd like to argue about.

Comment: You may be seeing ships traveling above or below the danger region. That’s how I have to transit (or super fast).